# CUDA generic dot product

Tags: cuda, dot-product

I'm new to both C and CUDA, and I was writing the dot product function, however it is not giving me the correct results. Will some kind soul help me take a look?

I also have two questions,

1. Why is dot() not working correctly, and
2. At line 57, why is it product[threadIdx.x] instead of product[index]? Can I not write

   product[index] = a[index] * b[index];
   ...
   if(index==0) {...}
   and sum each element with the zero-th thread this way?

Many thanks.

deviceQuery:

```
  Device 0: "GeForce GTX 570"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          6.0 / 5.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0
```

Makefile: nvcc -arch=sm_20 cuda_test.cu -o cuda_test

in cuda_test.cu:

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf, scanf, NULL etc.
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc, free, rand etc.

#define N (3) //Number of threads we are using (also, length of array declared in main)

#define THREADS_PER_BLOCK (1) //Threads per block we are using

#define N_BLOCKS (N/THREADS_PER_BLOCK)

/* Function to generate a random integer between 1-10 */
void random_ints (int *a, int n)
{
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL)); //Seed rand() with current time
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    { 
        a[i] = rand()%10 + 1; 
    }
    return;
}

/* Kernel that adds two integers a & b, stores result in c */
__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
//global indicates function that runs on 
//device (GPU) and is called from host (CPU) code

    int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    //threadIdx.x : thread index
    //blockIdx.x  : block index
    //blockDim.x  : threads per block
    //hence index is a thread counter across all blocks
    c[index] = a[index] + b[index];

//note that pointers are used for variables
//add() runs on device, so they must point to device memory
//need to allocate memory on GPU
}

/* Kernel for dot product */
__global__ void dot(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    __shared__ int product[THREADS_PER_BLOCK]; //All threads in a block must be able 
                                               //to access this array

    int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; //index

    product[threadIdx.x] = a[index] * b[index]; //result of elementwise
                                                //multiplication goes into product

    //Make sure every thread has finished
    __syncthreads();

    //Sum the elements serially to obtain dot product
    if( 0 == threadIdx.x ) //Pick one thread to sum, otherwise all will execute
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j=0; j < THREADS_PER_BLOCK; j++) sum += product[j];
        //Done!
        atomicAdd(c,sum);
    }
}

int main(void)
{

    int *a, *b, *c, *dotProduct; //host copies of a,b,c etc
    int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c, *d_dotProduct; //device copies of a,b,c etc

    int size = N * sizeof(int); //size of memory that needs to be allocated

    int i=0; //iterator

    //Allocate space for device copies of a,b,c
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c, size);

    //Setup input values
    a = (int *)malloc(size); random_ints(a,N);
    b = (int *)malloc(size); random_ints(b,N);
    c = (int *)malloc(size);

    //Copy inputs to device
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Launch add() kernel on GPU
    add<<<N_BLOCKS,THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c);
    // triple angle brackets mark call from host to device
    // this is also known as a kernel launch
    // N/THREADS_PER_BLOCK = NO. OF BLOCKS

    //Copy result back to host
    cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //Output results
    printf("a = {");
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) printf(" %d",a[i]);
    printf(" }\n");

    printf("b = {");
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) printf(" %d",b[i]);
    printf(" }\n");

    printf("c = {");
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) printf(" %d",c[i]);
    printf(" }\n");

    //Calculate dot product of a & b
    dotProduct = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); //Allocate host memory to dotProduct
    *dotProduct = 0; //initialise to zero
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_dotProduct, sizeof(int)); //Allocate device memory to d_dotProduct
    dot<<<N_BLOCKS,THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(d_a, d_b, d_dotProduct); //Perform calculation
    cudaMemcpy(dotProduct, d_dotProduct, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); //Copy result into dotProduct
    printf("\ndot(a,b) = %d\n", *dotProduct); //Output result

    //Cleanup
    free(a); free(b); free(c); free(dotProduct);
    cudaFree(d_a); cudaFree(d_b); cudaFree(d_c); cudaFree(d_dotProduct);

    return 0;
} //End of main
```

Comment: please post code without embedded line numbers that someone else could compile and run if they so wished. Also please explain what "not working correctly" means exactly.

Comment: hi talonmies,

sorry! i've cleaned it up and it should now compile. sorry for wasting your time earlier!

Answer (score 2):

As talonmies says, please make it so someone else could run your code. Embedding line numbers is unhelpful.

Best guess with no other information is that you have not initialised `d_dotProduct` to zero. You can do this with `cudaMemset()` - if you wanted a different initial value then you could `cudaMemcpy()` an initial value from the host or launch a separate kernel to initialise but in this case `cudaMemset()` (which is equivalent to `memset()` on the host) is sufficient.

It could also be that `N_BLOCKS*THREADS_PER_BLOCK` is not equal to `size`.

As for your second question, `product` is a per-block array of size `THREADS_PER_BLOCK`, if you access it with `product[index]` you'll be out-of-bounds.

Comment: hi tom,

thanks for answering Q2! i've cleaned up the code and included it in full. sorry for wasting your time earlier!

Answer (score -2):

problem solved! needed to set "*c = 0" before summing the individual elements of 'product' array.

```
/* Kernel for dot product */
__global__ void dot(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    __shared__ int product[THREADS_PER_BLOCK]; //All threads in a block must be able 
                                               //to access this array

    int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; //index

    product[threadIdx.x] = a[index] * b[index]; //result of elementwise
                                                //multiplication goes into product

    if(index==0) *c = 0; //Ask one thread to set c to zero.

    //Make sure every thread has finished
    __syncthreads();    

    //Sum the elements serially to obtain dot product
    if( 0 == threadIdx.x ) //Every block to do c += sum
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j=0; j < THREADS_PER_BLOCK; j++) sum += product[j];
        //Done!
        atomicAdd(c,sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, it will only work if you launch a single threadblock. If you launch more than one block, then thread zero of *each* block will reset the final result to zero. It would also be incorrect to only do this in block zero since the programming model allows blocks to execute in any order. The correct solution is to set d_dotProduct to zero *before* launching the kernel.

Comment: what about now? i added the if(index==0) *c=0 line.

how do u set d_dotProduct to zero from host code when it exists only on the GPU memory? you would have to do it from within the kernel surely?

P.S. thank you very much for your help, tom.

Comment: Like I said above, you cannot just do this set in block zero since blocks can execute in any order, e.g. block 1 could write its result before block 0 resets the result (overwriting block 1's result) to zero. The correct way to do this is to set the initial value to zero *before* launching the kernel - the most obvious way to do this is to use `cudaMemset()` but you could also use `cudaMemcpy()` to copy an initial value (zero, in this case) from the host. I'll add the *how* part to my answer.